# Regular Expression for AB1234567

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write regular expression for checking the length is exactly 9, the first two characters are letters and the last 7 characters are numbers?

I tried some thing like this

```
var regx = /^[A-Za-z]{2}d{7}$/;
```

Comment: I think it's because you are missing the `\` before `d`, making it just `d` instead of the character class `digit`. See my answer below.

Comment: Is the unsescaped `d` a typo? Other than that, it seems fine to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}$/;
```

Comment: No problem :) I'm happy to have been of help

Answer (score 4):

You're not giving a lot of extra info (like a working example), but I think you are looking for 7 `d`'s, and not digits. Try using `\d`

Answer (score 4):

The `d` should have been `\d` or `[0-9]`